# Android Volley - SQLite operations within a custom Request

Tags: android, android-volley

Is it possible to access the ContentResolver from within a custom Request.

In Ficus Kirkpatricks Google IO talk, he mentions that it's good to parse your JSON response within the custom request as it's done on the background thread for free. But from what I can tell I can't call getContentResolver() without caching Context.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Having just watched the same video, I think you might be over-reaching in interpreting 'parsing your JSON response' as involving a `ContentResolver`.

I took the 'JSON parsing' comment in the video to purely mean parsing the JSON to a relevant form e.g. a java object e.g. the way [this example](http://www.michenux.net/android-volley-and-gson-tutorial-797.html) creates a custom `GsonRequest` that extends `Request`.

Comment: I messaged Ficus on Twitter and he said to just keep a reference to Context when creating the request. I think this is a perfectly valid use case if you want to create a request you can just fire off and have it update a DB.